# Train NER in spacy v3 needs dev.spacy at command line

Tags: python, spacy-3

I am trying to prepare a custom ner model in spacy v3.
V3 has changed significantly as compared to v2 from training perspective.

I am Using the default config with en_web_lg.
I have prepared the training data (training.spacy) using convert command.
However, the training command needs a dev.spacy file.

Not sure what data is expected there in dev.spacy.
Is this asking a plain text corpus for the training.spacy file?
But then is there a way to convert the plain text file in spacy format..

Command from spacy site-
python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./dev.spacy

Can someone pls help explain on how to prep the dev.spacy.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the purpose of dev.spacy file. Usually, I have treated validation as a separate command. Good to see that now it is integrated in  training command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The train.spacy is a placeholder for collection of 'training' files - a directory of files usually using the Spacy convert utility.
The dev.spacy is a placeholder for collection of 'validation' files - same format as training files, but used as a validation sample during training (for NER used to compute the prediction, recall and f-score after each training iteration).
Commonly suggested 'size' of validation sample is between 10 to 20% of training sample.
I tend to use 20% because my data has a large variation - but larger validation sample adds training overhead.

Answer (score 4):

The `dev.spacy` file should look exactly the same as the `train.spacy` file, but should contain new examples that the training process hasn't seen before to get a realistic evaluation of the performance of your model.

To create this dev set, you can first split your original data into train/dev parts, and then run `convert` separately on each of them, calling the larger one `train.spacy` and the smaller one `dev.spacy`. As @mbrunecky suggests, an 80-20 split is usually good, but it depends on the dataset.

Comment: Thanks. yap that's a good factor. Though I prefer to keep it on low side ~10%/.